# Find two strings in list with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find two strings within a list that contains the characters from another string, which are not in order.  To make it clear, an example could be a list of animals like:

```
lion
dog
bear
cat
```

And a given string is: `oodilgn`.

The answer here would be: `lion` and `dog`

Each character from the string will be used only once.

Is there a regular expression that will allow me to do this?

Comment: This can be done using c# +Linq, do you have specific reason to use regex?

Comment: You could build a regex, but it would be ugly. There are easier, programmatic ways to solve this.

Comment: *Each character from the string will be used only once* ... per word or for all words ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the given string between `[]`. These brackets will allow choosing - in any order - from these letters only. This may not be a perfect solution, but it will catch the majority of your list.

For example, you could write `oodilgn` as `[oodilgn]`, then add a minimum number of letters to be found - let's say 3 - by using the curly brackets `{}`. The full regex will be like this:

```
[oodilgn]{3,}
```

This code basically says: find any word that has three of the letters that are located between brackets in any order.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/MCWHjQ/2

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim!  I will work with it and see what I can accomplish.  Thanks for the edit, btw, much appreciated!

Comment: @user6305383 My pleasure, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: *Each character from the string will be used only once* says OP

Comment: @Jim You're right, that's why I stated in my answer that `this may not be a perfect solution.`

Answer (score 0):

please try this out

```
Regex r=new Regex("^[.*oodilgn]$");
        var list=new List<String>(){"lion","dog","fish","god"};
        var output=list.Where(x=>r.IsMatch(x));
```

**result**

```
output=["lion","dog","god"];
```

Comment: make sure to implement the needed library like `regularexpression`
and `Linq`

Comment: *Each character from the string will be used only once* says OP

Comment: This regular expression will also match all off `lions`, `dogs` and `gods`. Perhaps a final `$` for end of string should be added. The *"only once"* part of the question is very hard to achieve with a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example algorithm that does the job. I have assumed that the two strings together don't need to take all letters from the text else i make additional commented check. Also i return first two appropriate answers.
Here is how you call it in the outside function, `Main` or else:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text = "oodilgn";
    var listOfWords = new List<string> { "lion", "dog", "bear", "cat" };
    ExtractWordsWithSameLetters(text, listOfWords);
}
```

Here is the function with the algorithm. All string manuplations are entirely with regex.

```
    public static void ExtractWordsWithSameLetters(string text, List<string> listOfWords)
    {
        string firstWord = null;
        string secondWord = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < listOfWords.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var textCopy = text;
            var firstWordIsMatched = true;
            foreach (var letter in listOfWords[i])
            {
                var pattern = $"(.*?)({letter})(.*?)";
                var regex = new Regex(pattern);
                if (regex.IsMatch(text))
                {
                    textCopy = regex.Replace(textCopy, "$1*$3", 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    firstWordIsMatched = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!firstWordIsMatched)
            {
                continue;
            }
            firstWord = listOfWords[i];

            for (var j = i + 1; j < listOfWords.Count; j++)
            {
                var secondWordIsMatched = true;
                foreach (var letter in listOfWords[j])
                {
                    var pattern = $"(.*?)({letter})(.*?)";
                    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
                    if (regex.IsMatch(text))
                    {
                        textCopy = regex.Replace(textCopy, "$1*$3", 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        secondWordIsMatched = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (secondWordIsMatched)
                {
                    secondWord = listOfWords[j];
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (secondWord == null)
            {
                firstWord = null;
            }
            else
            {
                //if (textCopy.ToCharArray().Any(l => l != '*'))
                //{
                //    break;
                //}
                break;
            }
        }

        if (firstWord != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{firstWord} { secondWord}");
        }
    }
```

Function is far from optimised but does what you want. If you want to return results, not print them just create an array and stuff `firstWord` and `secondWord` in it and have return type `string[]` or add two paramaters with `ref out` In those cases you will need to check the result in the calling function.